# a function from wordpress which i don't follow well

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function add_custom_background( $header_callback = '', $admin_header_callback = '', $admin_image_div_callback = '' ) {
    if ( isset( $GLOBALS['custom_background'] ) )
        return;

    if ( empty( $header_callback ) )
        $header_callback = '_custom_background_cb';

    add_action( 'wp_head', $header_callback );

    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array( 'callback' => $header_callback ) );

    if ( ! is_admin() )
        return;
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/custom-background.php' );
    $GLOBALS['custom_background'] =& new Custom_Background( $admin_header_callback, $admin_image_div_callback );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( &$GLOBALS['custom_background'], 'init' ) );
}
```

1, `$GLOBALS['custom_background'] =& new Custom_Background( $admin_header_callback, $admin_image_div_callback );`  what' the using of the sign `&` and the line meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you are assigning a reference to the variable in your globals array.

```
$GLOBALS['custom_background'] =& new Custom_Background( $admin_header_callback, $admin_image_div_callback );
```

Essentially, if you change the value of `$GLOBALS['custom_background']`, this affects the original variable itself (Custom_Background).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Keep in mind that objects are passed by reference by default.

Answer (score 1):

It has no special meaning, it's for the global reference.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

http://koivi.com/manual-php-globals/